# How to detect when iOS app appears in foreground, with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to detect when my app becomes visible? (for example by double tapping the Home button and then tapping on an app that is already in the background)
If possible, I would like to detect that event inside my UIViewController.
I am working with Swift 2.2.

Comment: Are you trying to detect when your app comes to the foreground or some other app?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, no need to downvote. @CodeBender

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` method of your `UIApplicationDelegate`. You should read up on the [app lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html). Your app delegate would then need to inform your view controller in some fashion.

Or you can register your view controller as an observer of the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification. Documentation for that can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification)

Comment: Clear and exact answer. Thank you